# In search of a word that means 'to make goodness manifest'

Tags: single-word-requests

Does the English language contain a word that bears the meaning 'to make goodness manifest'?

I have found that 'condemn' holds a meaning in close opposite to this, but I have yet to find a suitable antonym.

Any and all help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you!  That is close to what I'm looking for, but not as precise as I'd hoped. Webster's says in a definition for condemn:
"make manifest the faults of" http://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/unabridged/Condemn                                   I am looking for an antonym to this extent if that helps at all.

Comment: Can you please show us an example of the context in which you plan to use it. It would help immensely. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the opposite of condemn, the most accurate word would be `Praise`.

Comment: Please edit in the definition of praise, to explain why that word is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

It might help to look at the [antonyms of *condemn*](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/condemn?s=t).

From those, I'd recommend [*exalt*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/exalt?s=t).

Answer (score 0):

Vindicate, [meaning](https://www.lexico.com/definition/vindicate)

> Clear (someone) of blame or suspicion.

or

> Show or prove to be right, reasonable, or justified.

is pretty much the antonym of "condemn."